# Online-Only Availabilty OneDrive files still consuming space

Tags: hard-drive, onedrive

I have a video library in OneDrive that I want configured so they do not consume local hard drive space.  To do that, I right-click the top level folder and choose "Make Available Online Only".  When I analyze my drive I still see no improvement in space.  I have also analyzed by drive using WinDirStat and I can see large blobs of videos consuming drive space.   Why is this setting not increasing my hard drive free-space?

Comment: Is this OneDrive on Windows 8?

Comment: Windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: Is the physical file there or these videos smart files ( i.e. placeholders ) here?  I suspect you still have the physical file if its larger then a few Megabytes.  Word of advice this behavior is going to change in the future, smart files won't exist more, once Windows 10 is released.

Comment: I assume they are suppose to be "Smart" files but apparently are not.  What way is there to tell other than the Availability flag stating it is Offline only?